# How could a spring-boot application determine if it is running on cloud foundry?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm writting a micro service with spring-boot. The db is mongodb. The service works perfectly in my local environment. But after I deployed it to the cloud foundry it doesn't work. The reason is connecting mongodb time out.

I think the root cause is the application doesn't know it is running on cloud. Because it still connecting 127.0.0.1:27017, but not the redirected port.

How could it know it is running on cloud? Thank you!

EDIT:

There is a mongodb instance bound to the service. And when I checked the environment information, I got following info:

```
{
    "VCAP_SERVICES": {
        "mongodb": [
            {
                "credentials": {
                    "hostname": "10.11.241.1",
                    "ports": {
                        "27017/tcp": "43417",
                        "28017/tcp": "43135"
                    },
                    "port": "43417",
                    "username": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                    "password": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                    "dbname": "gwkp7glhw9tq9cwp",
                    "uri": "xxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                "syslog_drain_url": null,
                "volume_mounts": [],
                "label": "mongodb",
                "provider": null,
                "plan": "v3.0-container",
                "name": "mongodb-business-configuration",
                "tags": [
                    "mongodb",
                    "document"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
        "cf_api": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "limits": {
            "fds": 16384,
            "mem": 1024,
            "disk": 1024
        },
        "application_name": "mock-service",
        "application_uris": [
            "xxxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        "name": "mock-service",
        "space_name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "space_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "uris": [
            "xxxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        "users": null,
        "application_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "version": "c7569d23-f3ee-49d0-9875-8e595ee76522",
        "application_version": "c7569d23-f3ee-49d0-9875-8e595ee76522"
    }
}
```

From my understanding, I think my spring-boot service should try to connect the port 43417 but not 27017, right? Thank you!

Comment: Because you don't actually have a [`mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) service on the same instance as the application? How about pointing to a remote MongoDB instead. https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+hosting+providers

Comment: There is actually an official documentation section in "ecosystem"  on this: [VMware Cloud Foundry](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/platforms/vmware-cloud-foundry/)

Comment: Thank you both, and actually there is an mongodb instance bounded to the service. I also edit the question to declare it.

Comment: If you actually read the documentation there the "instance" is still not on the same machine. You need to point to the address where it is rather than 'localhost'. You clearly are not reading it because you just called "both" what is actually just "me". Read the documentation. It's not `localhost` but another IP address.\

Comment: Are you using the Spring Cloud Foundry connector? https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/configuring-service-connections/spring-service-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason is I didn't specify the profile. After adding following code in my manifest.yml it works:

```
env:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right, you should,'t have to do that. What cloudfoundry distribution are you using?